# xcode 6 opening view controller by click

Tags: ios, xcode, button, viewcontroller

This is my `ViewController`'s code:

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
    twentysixViewController *detailScreen=[[twentysixViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"twentysixViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailScreen animated:YES];
}
```

Also I import my  `twentysixViewController` in `ViewController`.

```
#import "twentysixViewController.h"
```

This is `twentysixViewController`'s code

```
#import "twentysixViewController.h"

@interface twentysixViewController ()

@end

@implementation twentysixViewController

   - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}
```

But when I click on button in `ViewController`, another `twentysixViewController` didn't open. Also I create `twentysixViewController` with XIB file.

Comment: Did you link your button's action in your xib?

Comment: Yeah, check the action is linked on button in xib, check the code on it is been called by setting a break point

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you are using segues?

You can make a segue from main view controller to twentyViewController. When that button clicked call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil];
```

Don't forget to change `segueIdentifier` with appropriate segue identifier which you specified in interface builder.

Comment: Thak's. How I can set segueIdentifer in twentyViewController?